# HTTP/2 compatibility API, how to handle it

Tags: node.js, https, http2, alpn

While initially I had settled for creating an HTTP/2 only server, I found the compatibility API to be a good option to support clients without, or with unknown, HTTP/2 support (`fetch` in `react-native`?).

However, I am struggling to understand how to deal with incoming requests on the HTTP/1x handler, that report `req.httpVersion === "2.0"`. The following code is an extract from the [`ALPN negotiation section`](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#alpn-negotiation) in the `nodejs` documentation:

```js
function onRequest(req, res) {
  // Detects if it is a HTTPS request or HTTP/2
  const { socket: { alpnProtocol } } = req.httpVersion === '2.0' ?
    req.stream.session : req;

  // HERE: OK, say we have  req.httpVersion === '2.0'
  // Now, what?

  res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'application/json' });
  res.end(JSON.stringify({
    alpnProtocol,
    httpVersion: req.httpVersion
  }));
}
```

First of all, I do not understand what the code above is supposed to do. Like, I know what it does, but there isn't anything particular to it - seems just generic HTTP/1x request handler, that sends some JSON back, and nothing more. Did I miss anything?

Other than that:

- once the HTTP/1x handler reports `req.httpVersion = "2.0"`, what do I do about it?
  Will it also be handled by the HTTP/2 handler (`server.on("stream", ()=>{ ... })`), so I should just ignore it in the HTTP/1x handler?
- If it won't be handled by the HTTP/2 handler automatically, can -and should- I just forward the request to the HTTP/2 handler manually?

```js
function http2handler(stream, headers){ ... }

function http1xhandler(req, res) {
  if (req.httpVersion === "2.0") {
    // handle as HTTP/2
    return http2handler(req.stream, req.headers);
  }

  // handle as HTTP/1x ...
}

const server = createSecureServer(
  { cert, key, allowHTTP1: true },
  http1xhandler
).listen(4443);

server.on("stream", http2handler);
```

- If none of the above, does the response JSON in the example play any role into indicating to the client that it should switch to HTTP/2? And if so, what exactly should the client do?

Sorry if this may be a dumb question, the nodejs documentation is awful... it seems like every bit of their documentation must end in a cliffhanger...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddling with some code and reading more articles and answers, I think I have finally understood what goes on. I would however appreciate any feedback if anything I say here is wrong.

The HTTP/2 compatibility API provides **a common request handler for both HTTP/1x and HTTP/2 requests**. As indicated by the [ALPN negotiation documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#alpn-negotiation), the developer should limit the response to the public HTTP/1x API - until an HTTP/2 request has been identified. You can check the [`req.httpVersion`](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#requesthttpversion) to identify these, and branch your code as needed.

If you specify both a compatibility request handler (callback function on `createSecureServer`), and an `on("stream", ...)` event handler (which is HTTP/2 only), the server behavior is:

- for HTTP/1x requests, only the compatibility request handler will be called
- for HTTP/2 requests, **both** the the compatibility, and the `on("stream", ...)` request handlers will be called - **but only one of the handlers should ever respond to the request**. If you try to respond to the request from both handlers you will get:
  `Error [ERR_HTTP2_HEADERS_SENT]: Response has already been initiated.`

The way that I have chosen to deal with these is to create independent `HTTP/1x` and `HTTP/2` handlers, each dealing with it's own cake. The compatiblity handler should ignore HTTP/2 requests. In code:

```
function http1xhandler(req, res) {
  if (req.httpVersion === "2.0") {
    // Ignore HTTP/2 requests, will be handled by the on("stream", ...) event handler
    // Or, you can answer the HTTP/2 request here, using HTTP/2 features as well
    return;
  }

  // Handle HTTP/1x request
  res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end("Hello HTTP/1x!");
}

const server = createSecureServer(
  { cert, key, allowHTTP1: true },
  http1xhandler
).listen(4443);

// Do not use the following if you are handling
// HTTP/2 in the HTTP/1x compatibility callback

function http2handler(stream, headers){
  stream.respond({
      'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
      ':status': 200
    });
  stream.end("Hello HTTP/2!");
}

server.on("stream", http2handler);
```

Hopefully this will be useful to someone else looking into these APIs.